# Can I still restore a crypt8 whatsapp backup from mid-2015 on Android in 2023?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I still have the same phone number. Is this local backup too old to restore?

Is there a limit on how old a backup I can restore on whatsapp?

On, https://faq.whatsapp.com/618575946635920/?cms_platform=android , it seems possible to restore older backups, however the example formats are crypt9+

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Nothing. However I'd like to know before I try...